# iTerm won't run on my OS X system. Troubleshooting ideas?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, iterm

I just installed iTerm 0.10 on my OS X Snow Leopard system. When I try to launch it, the menu bar says "iTerm" for about a tenth of a second and then it vanishes. It's not listed in the Activity Monitor.

Has anyone gotten iTerm to run on Snow Leopard? Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. Post a crash log.

Comment: Where would I find the logging output?

Comment: In Console (`/Applications/Utilities/`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing, ~/Library/Preferences/net.sourceforge.iTerm.plist and start it again. Snow Lepord has some known issues with iTerm.